# Transact SQL Print only first letter using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue. I have declared a cursor and when i fetch it i want to print a variable (type nvarchar) but for each row i get only the first letter
Here is my code :

```
DECLARE @loginSoftware nvarchar
DECLARE @loginId int
DECLARE @softwareId int
DECLARE @passwordSoftware nvarchar
DECLARE @SoftwareFamily nvarchar
DECLARE @SoftwareName nvarchar
DECLARE @password nvarchar
DECLARE Get_Password cursor 
        for (select loginId, charly.softwareId, login, password FROM REFC_SOFTWARE_LOGIN, v_charly_HOSTS_AND_SOFTS_INFOS charly 
                  WHERE charly.softwareId = REFC_SOFTWARE_LOGIN.softwareId
                  AND charly.SoftwareFamily = 'DB'
                  and SoftwareName in ('Oracle', 'SQL Server', 'MYSQL') )

OPEN Get_Password 

FETCH NEXT FROM Get_Password INTO @loginId, @softwareId, @loginSoftware, @passwordSoftware

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
BEGIN 

--raiserror (@passwordSoftware, 10,1) with nowait 
SET @password = @passwordSoftware
PRINT @password 
FETCH NEXT FROM Get_Password INTO @loginId, @softwareId, @loginSoftware,   @passwordSoftware
END 

CLOSE Get_Password
DEALLOCATE Get_Password
```

What do I need to change for printing the entire variable's value ?
Did I made any mistake ?

In advance thanks for your help and your time

Comment: I think you need to read [DECLARE @local_variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECLARE @loginSoftware NVARCHAR

SET @loginSoftware = 'fdjafs'

PRINT @loginSoftware

### Will give you only the first letter.

DECLARE @loginSoftware NVARCHAR (2000)

SET @loginSoftware = 'fdjafs'

PRINT @loginSoftware

Will give you all of it....So basically you also have to specify the data length too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick answer that's work fine now

Answer (score 1):

Make you `nvarchar` variables have a length.  If you don't declare is like `nvarchar(20)` then the default length is 1.

Answer (score 1):

`NVARCHAR`'s default length is 1. You must declare it with length.